# How to match text from select with array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have select with few options

```
<select id="delivery">
 <option>London</option>
 <option>Berlin</option>
 <option>Paris</option>
</select>
```

I have such js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 function valParam () {
  var cities = [
   { city: 'London', koef: 1, mag: 34.2},
   { city: 'Berlin', koef: 1.25, mag: 34.2},
   { city: 'Paris', koef: 1.25, mag: 11.7}
  ];    
  var text= $('#text').val(); 
  };    

  $('.calculator').on('change', valParam);

})
```

I need to get `koef` and `mag` from arr which match to text in selected option. 
After that I need to use this values in calcultaions `result = (text + koef) * mag`

How to match text from select with array in js and save these values?

Comment: Use a for loop to go through your array and see if what's inside the select tag matched the city's name. If it does then store it in another variable perhaps.

Comment: Are you creating options dynamically ?

Comment: @RayonDabre it is static

Comment: @Voreny the problem is that I don't understand how to make it with code

Comment: I didn't try all variant, I've just chosen the one which was more understandable for me. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that `#text` is an input which contains a numeric value
(you didn't write anything about it in the question)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function valParam () {
        var city = $('#delivery').val();
        var text = parseFloat($('#text').val()); 
        var result = null;
        var cities = [
            { city: 'London', koef: 1, mag: 34.2},
            { city: 'Berlin', koef: 1.25, mag: 34.2},
            { city: 'Paris', koef: 1.25, mag: 11.7}
        ];    

        for (var ind = 0, ln = cities.length; ind < ln; ind++){
            if (cities[ind].city === city){
                result = (text + cities[ind].koef) * cities[ind].mag;     
                break;
            }
        }

        // here 'result' should have the calc you need.
        alert(result);
    };    

    $('.calculator').on('change', valParam);

})
```

---

I can't create a properly JsFiddle because I do not even know what is `.calculator` too, but [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/usLuaopv/) a "workaround" of my above code for testing  .

**Code Tests:**
 if `#text` value is *3* ..
 - London result = 136.8
 - Berlin result = 145.35000000000002
 - Paris result  = 49.724999999999994

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick ...

```
$.each(cities,function(i,c){
  if(c.city == $("#delivery option:selected").text()){
    // do something here
    result = (text + c.koef)*c.mag;
  }
});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have selected option from the dropdown then it will look like this-

```
<select id="delivery">
 <option>London</option>
 <option selected="selected">Berlin</option>
 <option>Paris</option>
</select>
```

you can get the value of selected option from the below code-

```
var e = document.getElementById("delivery");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

After this you have to match this text value by iterating your array in valParam() function and you can get value of koef and mag easily.

I think above will solve your query.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your `cities` array into an object/map and just use the name of the city as the key:

```
var cities = {
  'London': { koef: 1, mag: 34.2 },
  'Berlin': { koef: 1.25, mag: 34.2 },
  'Paris': { koef: 1.25, mag: 11.7 },
  'New York': {...}
};
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
var selectedOption = $( "#delivery option:selected" ).text();
var cityData = cities[selectedOption];
var result = (text + cityData.koef) * cityData.mag;

// Note that I'm a bit confused by your formula since you can't multiple strings, and I'm assuming here that text is a string?
```

Comment: check the json format + why did you change the `cities` from array to object? yes it's better if it's an object to fast get the selected city, but maybe op need that variable as an array

Comment: @Saba ty for typo catch. Maybe OP does, maybe OP doesn't. This is simply an offered solution that I think is easier to reason about and deal with (and that is much more performant)

Comment: I have problem with "New York" city - error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @angelzzz for keys with spaces you will need to explicitly define all keys in their string form. See my updated answer. Basically just quote all the key values. When you access, just make sure to always use `key[value]` form instead of the `key.value`. For example, `cities['New York']` is valid but `cities.New York` is not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cities = [
   { city: 'London', koef: 1, mag: 34.2},
   { city: 'Berlin', koef: 1.25, mag: 34.2},
   { city: 'Paris', koef: 1.25, mag: 11.7}
  ];  

  $('#delivery').on('change', function() {  
    cities.forEach(function(obj)
    {
      if (obj.city == $('#delivery').val())
        {
          
           var res = (parseFloat($('#text').val())
 + obj.koef) * obj.mag;
          
           $('#result').html(res);
             
        }
      
    });
  });

// initialize it
$('#delivery').val('London').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="delivery">
 <option>London</option>
 <option>Berlin</option>
 <option>Paris</option>
</select>

<input id='text' value='3'>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Looks like your code uses value in input as text, not number

Comment: it doens't work correctly - for London (3 + 1) * 34.2 = 136.8, not 160.2